# Bad collapse animation of sidebar

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation, sidebar

I have a problem on an animation that I would improve .

[image]

As you can see , when you close the sidebar , we have a not very pleasant " collapse" style effect

The jquery code is

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");

});
```

http://www.bootply.com/2BqP3cR0GL#

You can change this animation with another ? Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the wrapping, try animating the `left` attribute to a negative number; so if the menu is 200px wide animate left between `left: 0px;` for visible and `left:-200px;` for hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `width` to `#MainMenu` div container. For example:

```
#MainMenu { width:240px; } // Width be any value.
```